# Nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, fixnum

I have the following function:

```
def valid_credit_card?(number)
    digits = number.scan(/./).map(&:to_i)
    check = digits.pop

    sum = digits.reverse.each_slice(2).map do |x, y|
        [(x * 2).divmod(10), y]
    end.flatten.inject(:+)

    (10 - sum % 10) == check
end
```

But for some reason I keep getting the following error message:
`nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`

And for some reason I can't figure out why the error is being thrown. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your method fails when `digits` has an odd number of elements. In that case, when you call `each_slice(2)` on the last iteration, `x` will be the last element of `digits` and `y` will be `nil`. So when you get to the `inject(:+)` phase, the last element of the array is `nil`, and your coercion error happens when the interpreter hits something like `2 + nil`.

Why not add an initial check on the number of digits inputted? Something like:

```
return false unless digits.length == 16
```

Comment: ah, that makes sense! How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: The problem with returning false if the digits don't equal 16 means that not all credit cards will pass the Luhn Algorithm (which is what the function above is supposed to do)